# Résidence un/une, partie un/une

Tags: grammaire, genre, nombres

Je voudrais savoir la forme prise par "un" lorsque on l'utilise pour qualifier un nom féminin. Par exemple,

> J'habite à résidence un/une (il y  a 4 résidences)
>
> La partie un/une de cours est le plus difficile.

Dans les conversations quotidiennes, j'entends les deux formes et ça me gène.

Answer (score 4):

*J'habite **à** résidence **un/une*** est incorrect. On peut dire:

> *J'habite [à] la résidence **numéro un***

ou

> *J'habite [à] la résidence un[e]*

ou

> *j'habite **la première** résidence*.

Idem pour *La partie un/une de cours est le plus difficile*

> *La **première partie** de **ce** cours est **la** plus difficile*

Il est aussi possible de considérer *un* ou *une* comme le nom (le titre) de la partie en question (ou le nom de la résidence), comme on aurait pu aussi dire *la partie A*, *la partie B*. Dans ce cas, les deux genres sont possibles:

> *La partie **un** de ce cours est la plus difficile*

ou

> *La partie **une** de ce cours est la plus difficile*

Comment: *La partie un(e)* is not always incorrect, it can still be found in some contexts: if a document or a book is subdivided in multiple sections, they may be titled "Partie 1", "Partie 2", etc. There you may say *partie un(e*) as referring to the numbering of the "parties. Ex: *j'ai commencé à étudier ce cours. La partie 1 est très difficile, mais la partie 2 est plus facile, et la partie 3 se compose d'exercices.* But I don't know if there is a rule whether it should be *partie un* or *partie *une*. I would personally think both can be heard.

Comment: @Greg Oui, c'est vrai. Réponse mise à jour. Merci. PS: Pourquoi ce commentaire en anglais alors que la question (à part le *hi* qu'il faudrait supprimer) et la réponse sont en français ?

Comment: .... oui... je devais avoir mis mon cerveau en mode monolingue anglais, il n'y avait aucune raison de commenter en anglais...

Comment: Je vois pas de problème avec "*J'habite **à la** résidence un(e)*" ou "*J'habite **dans la** résidence un(e)*". "*J'habite la résidence*" sonne un peu trop formel je trouve.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je n'y vois pas de problème non plus. L'erreur que j'avais souligné concerne *j'habite **à résidence***. Je clarifie ma réponse.

Comment: merci les gars pour la clarification :). J'ai posé cette question parce que il y avait un jour je disait "j'habite à la résidence un" et on m'a répondu "tu habites à la résidence UNE?" avec une forte emphase sur le une. lol